# ManagedSynonymFilterFactory is giving empty managedMap

Tags: solr, lucene

I am a newbie to Solr. I have enabled ManagedSynonymFilterFactory in schema.xml file as shown below

```
<fieldType name="managed_en" class="solr.TextField" positionIncrementGap="100">
  <analyzer>
    <tokenizer class="solr.StandardTokenizerFactory"/>
    <filter class="solr.ManagedStopFilterFactory" managed="english" />
    <filter class="solr.ManagedSynonymFilterFactory" managed="english" />
  </analyzer>
</fieldType>
```

Now i am trying to hit http://localhost:8983/solr/testcore/schema/analysis/synonyms/english iam getting response as

```
{  "responseHeader":{
"status":0,
"QTime":2},"synonymMappings":{
"initArgs":{"ignoreCase":false},
"initializedOn":"2016-09-17T05:40:31.245Z",
"managedMap":{}}}
```

though i have defined synonyms in synonyms.txt file. When i search synonym i getting the results from the Solr properly. But not sure why i am getting empty in the managed map.

P.S: Using Solr 5.4.1

Comment: The synonyms that you have defined in **synonym.txt** is used by **SynonymFilterFactory** not by **ManagedSynonymFilterFactory**. ManagedSynonymFilterFactory used different file named **_schema_analysis_synonyms_english.json**. To add synonym to ManagedSynonymFilterFactory, use solr managed resource REST API

Answer (score 1):

When you define words in synonym.txt then it is used by  SynonymFilterFactory  not by the ManagedSynonymFilterFactory.

```
<filter class="solr.SynonymFilterFactory" expand="true" synonyms="synonyms.txt" ignoreCase="true"/>
```

The reason you are getting proper results because the solr field in which you performing search using the SynonymFilterFactory instead of ManagedSynonymFilterFactory.

To add words to the ManagedSynonymFilterFactory you need to use Solr Managed Resources REST API. 
To add a new synonym mapping, you can PUT/POST a single mapping such as:

```
curl -X PUT -H 'Content-type:application/json' --data-binary
'{"mad":["angry","upset"]}'
"http://localhost:8983/solr/techproducts/schema/analysis/synonyms/english"
```

For more information
https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/solr/Managed+Resources

Comment: So in that case synonyms.txt is different from the ManagedSynonymFilterFactory synonyms entries..? i have tried to use the above curl command but i am getting 500 error.C:\Users\kavarana>curl -X PUT -H 'Content-type:application/json' --data-binary '{"mad":["angry","upset"]}' "http://localhost:8983/solr/fridays/schema/
analysis/synonyms/english"
{
  "responseHeader":{
    "status":500,
    "QTime":3},
  "error":{
    "msg":"Bad Request",
    "trace":"Bad Request (400) - Invalid content type application/x-www-form-urlencoded; only application/json is supported.\r\n\tat org.apache

Comment: @user2784095 I have tried the above command and its working. Could you please try it with **cURL version 7.50.3-1**.

Comment: I am using the same version C:\Users\kavarana>curl --version
curl 7.50.3 (x86_64-pc-win32) libcurl/7.50.3 OpenSSL/1.0.2h nghttp2/1.14.1
Protocols: dict file ftp ftps gopher http https imap imaps ldap pop3 pop3s rtsp
Features: AsynchDNS IPv6 Largefile NTLM SSL HTTP2

Comment: @user2784095 I'm running this command on cygwin which I have freshly installed on my system and there is no bad request error. Try to install the cygwin. May be that will remove the error.